# TypeScript error: node_modules/@types/three/three-core.d.ts(767,24): Error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Iterable'

Tags: typescript, three.js

I have this error:

> TypeScript error: node_modules/@types/three/three-core.d.ts(767,24):
>   Error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Iterable'.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wmkxk.png)

I use gulp workflow from this instruction: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/gulp.html

I installed TypeScript 2.2.2 for VS2015.

This is full code:

```
import * as THREE from "three";

// https://github.com/pinqy520/three-typescript-starter/blob/master/src/index.ts
class Game
{
    private _scene: THREE.Scene;
    //private _canvas: HTMLCanvasElement;
    private _camera: THREE.PerspectiveCamera;
    private _renderer: THREE.WebGLRenderer;
    private _axis: THREE.AxisHelper;
    private _light: THREE.DirectionalLight;
    private _light2: THREE.DirectionalLight;
    private _material: THREE.MeshBasicMaterial;
    private _box: THREE.Mesh;

    public constructor()
    {
        //this._canvas = <HTMLCanvasElement>document.getElementById(canvasElement);
        this._scene = new THREE.Scene();
        this._camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
        this._renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
        this._axis = new THREE.AxisHelper(10);
        this._light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 1.0);
        this._light2 = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 1.0);
        this._material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
            color: 0xaaaaaa,
            wireframe: true
        });
        this._box = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 1), this._material);
    }

    public createScene(): void
    {
        this._renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
        document.body.appendChild(this._renderer.domElement);
        this._scene.add(this._axis);
        this._light.position.set(100, 100, 100);
        this._scene.add(this._light);
        this._light2.position.set(-100, 100, -100)
        this._scene.add(this._light2);
        this._box.position.x = 0.5;
        this._box.rotation.y = 0.5;

        this._camera.position.x = 5;
        this._camera.position.y = 5;
        this._camera.position.z = 5;

        this._camera.lookAt(this._scene.position);
    }

    public animate(): void
    {
        requestAnimationFrame(this.animate);
        this._render();
    }

    private _render(): void
    {
        let timer = 0.002 * Date.now()
        this._box.position.y = 0.5 + 0.5 * Math.sin(timer)
        this._box.rotation.x += 0.1
        this._renderer.render(this._scene, this._camera)
    }
}

window.onload = () =>
{
    let game = new Game();
    game.createScene();
    game.animate();
}
```

Comment: In tsconfig.json under compilerOptions, specify `"lib": ["esnext"]`

Comment: Yes it works, but another error: TypeScript error: Error TS2318: Cannot find global type 'Array'.

Comment: add `"dom"` to the `"lib"` array

Comment: Yes, I added

{
  "files": [
    "src/Game.ts"
  ],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [ "esnext", "dom" ]
  }
}

But: TypeScript error: Error TS2318: Cannot find global type 'Array'.

Comment: You shouldn't use both the `///<reference path>` directive and `import`.

Comment: If you can show where the array error is coming from it might be helpful

Comment: I deleted this line: import * as THREE from "../node_modules/@types/three/three-core";

But again: TypeScript error: Error TS2318: Cannot find global type 'Array'.

Comment: you should have deleted the reference path instead of the import anyway. Reference path is evil

Comment: Yes I deleted. Now it is:
import * as THREE from "../node_modules/@types/three/three-core";

But I do not know where is the global type 'Array'?

Comment: It's declared in the library esnext. I meant where the error was being raised try using array in your own code and see what happens. Also validate your typescript installation. Write `declare const a: Array<{}>;` and choose go to definition on array. If it doesn't find anything....

Comment: I just noticed you're importing from a relative path that leads into node modules never do that just import from 'three'. I still shouldn't cause this error but it will mean that your code will explode at run time.

Comment: Where to write it? In Game.ts?

Comment: sure, it's just a test to see if the compiler can resolve the type

Comment: I tried to write declare const a: Array<{}>; in Game.ts and in three-core.d.ts it writes: Cannot find name 'Array'

Comment: What if you use the command line? Maybe your Visual Studio tools are out of date.

Comment: Try `"lib": ["es2017", "dom"]`

Comment: Yes, I wrote: import * as THREE from "three"; it works. But how to solve this error after gulp command: TypeScript error: Error TS2318: Cannot find global type 'Array'.

Comment: So the errors is coming from gulp? Make sure everything's up to date your version of TypeScript is also out of date

Comment: Create a new project

Comment: Yes from gulp. I updated VS2015 Typescript from here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48593

Comment: Anyway if the errors coming from Gulp then it's nothing to do with Visual Studio. So you should try another toolchain

Comment: I created a new project but it is as well as before

VS 2015 - TypeScrpt 2.2.2
tsc -v
2.3.2

Comment: Why do you need gulp? Maybe your gulp typescript plug-in is out of date maybe you aren't configuring it right but get the simple scenario working first. Get it to work with TSC from the command line and work your way up to other tools if you're having difficulty.

Comment: But this workflow works for BabylonJS and Phaser:
https://8observer8.bitbucket.io/BabylonJS/GettingStarted/dist/
https://8observer8.bitbucket.io/Phaser/BattleCity/dist/

Comment: I see, I'm afraid I don't know enough about that particular package. Maybe file an issue on their repository.

Comment: Because gulp creates bundle.js and uglify it

Comment: Add the solution as an answer instead of updating your own post.

Comment: Yes, I did. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Solution is: "lib": [ "es2015", "dom" ]

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "files": [
    "src/Game.ts"
  ],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [ "es2015", "dom" ]
  }
}
```

The fixed code example: http://codepen.io/8Observer8/pen/oWoXyz

```
/// <reference path="../../node_modules/@types/three/index.d.ts" />

//import * as THREE from "three";
// this line does't work. Error: Cannot find module 'three' from ...

// https://github.com/pinqy520/three-typescript-starter/blob/master/src/index.ts

class Game
{
    private _scene: THREE.Scene;
    //private _canvas: HTMLCanvasElement;
    private _camera: THREE.PerspectiveCamera;
    private _renderer: THREE.WebGLRenderer;
    private _axis: THREE.AxisHelper;
    private _light: THREE.DirectionalLight;
    private _light2: THREE.DirectionalLight;
    private _material: THREE.MeshBasicMaterial;
    private _box: THREE.Mesh;

    public constructor()
    {
        //this._canvas = <HTMLCanvasElement>document.getElementById(canvasElement);
        this._scene = new THREE.Scene(); // create the scene
        // create the camera
        this._camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
        this._renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
        this._axis = new THREE.AxisHelper(10); // add axis to the scene
        this._light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 1.0); // add light1
        this._light2 = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 1.0); // add light2
        this._material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
            color: 0xaaaaaa,
            wireframe: true
        });
        // create a box and add it to the scene
        this._box = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 1), this._material);
    }

    public createScene(): void
    {
        // set size
        this._renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
        document.body.appendChild(this._renderer.domElement); // add canvas to dom
        this._scene.add(this._axis);
        this._light.position.set(100, 100, 100);
        this._scene.add(this._light);
        this._light2.position.set(-100, 100, -100)
        this._scene.add(this._light2);
        this._scene.add(this._box)
        this._box.position.x = 0.5;
        this._box.rotation.y = 0.5;

        this._camera.position.x = 5;
        this._camera.position.y = 5;
        this._camera.position.z = 5;

        this._camera.lookAt(this._scene.position);
    }

    public animate(): void
    {
        console.log("animate");
        requestAnimationFrame(this.animate.bind(this));
        this._render();
    }

    private _render(): void
    {
        let timer = 0.002 * Date.now();
        this._box.position.y = 0.5 + 0.5 * Math.sin(timer);
        this._box.rotation.x += 0.1;
        this._renderer.render(this._scene, this._camera);
    }
}

window.onload = () =>
{
    let game = new Game();
    game.createScene();
    game.animate();
}
```

Comment: "lib": [ "es2015", "dom" ] worked for me, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Adding this to the top of my typescript file fixed this issue for me:

```
///<reference path="./node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es6.d.ts"/>
```